# reactive redis hgetall processing

Tags: redis, reactive-programming, spring-data-redis, lettuce

What is the code below lacking to initiate processing here, apparently this code does nothing, in this form.
I can call the block on flux result and collect in a list and process without using the subscriber which does works, howver i am looking to use a subscriber here and use onNext(...) to process each record neatly.

```
Flux<KeyValue<String,String>> result = redisReactiveCommands.hgetall("SomeRecords");
    result.subscribe(new Subscriber<KeyValue<String, String>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Subscription subscription) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(KeyValue<String, String> stringStringKeyValue) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable throwable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {

        }
    });
```